# Proving that $x,y \in \ell^2(\Bbb N) \implies x+y \in \ell^2(\Bbb N)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I want to prove that $x,y \in \ell^2(\Bbb N) \implies x+y \in \ell^2(\Bbb N)$. I'm damn sure that there is a quick way to do this, but I'm not seeing it. I am capable of proving Young, Hölder and Minkowski's inequalities to estabilish the result for $\ell^p(\Bbb N)$, but that seems overkill here and I don't want to do that.

Can someone point me the way, please? Thanks.

**Obs.:** $\ell^2(\Bbb N) = \left\{  (x_n)_{n \in \Bbb N} \mid x_n \in \Bbb C~ \forall\,n, \text{ and } \sum_{n \in \Bbb N}|x_n|^2 < +\infty \right\}$

Comment: what does $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ mean? The space of all sequences of natural numbers such that the series over the squared numbers converges?

Comment: I added the definition in an edit.

Comment: Doesn't this follow directly from the triangle inequality of the $\ell^2$ norm ?

Comment: I could prove that $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{n \in \Bbb N}x_n\overline{y_n}$ defines an inner product then. So everything goes at once. But I was thinking that there was a direct proof of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely cloddish inequality: If $a,b \ge 0,$ then $(a+b)^2 \le 4a^2 + 4 b^2.$ Proof: If $a\le b,$ then the left side is $\le (2b)^2 = 4b^2,$ same idea of course if $a\ge b.$ So $$\sum (x_n+y_n)^2 \le \sum (|x_n|+|y_n|)^2 \le \sum (4|x_n|^2 + 4|y_n|^2)$$ and that does it.

Comment: I loved it! ${}{}$

Comment: just to be sure, why do we have $(x_n+y_n)^2 \leq (|x_n|+|y_n|)^2$? I understand that $x_n \leq |x_n|$ and $y_n \leq |y_n|$, so that $x_n+y_n \leq |x_n|+|y_n|$, but if $x_n+y_n < 0$ we can't square both sides and mantain $\leq$

Comment: Nevermind, I got it

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the triangle inequality of the$\ell^2$ norm, since $x,y \in \ell^2$ then $\|x\|_2 <\infty $ and $\|y\|_2 <\infty$ thus 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty |x_n + y_n|^2 =\| x+ y\|_2^2 \leq (\|x\|_2+\|y\|_2)^2 < \infty 
$$
Hence, indeed $x+y \in \ell^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** multiply out the terms in the sum for $||x + y||$, and use Cauchy-Schwarz to find a bound for $\sum x_iy_i$ in terms of $||x||$ and $||y||$.

Comment: Remember that, while Cauchy-Schwarz is a special case of Holder, it is easier to prove.

Comment: Well, I have: $$\sum |x_n+y_n|^2 = \sum |x_n|^2+\sum |y_n|^2+2 \sum |x_ny_n|,$$so the issue is bounding $\sum |x_ny_n|$. But Cauchy-Schwarz would give $$\left| \sum x_n\overline{y_n}\right| \leq \left(\sum |x_n|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum|y_n|^2\right)^{1/2},$$ not quite what I need...

Comment: @IvoTerek There's no need to take the modulus/absolute value inside the summation during your derivation. Set your overall goal as bounding $\left|\sum (x_i + y_i)\overline{(x_i + y_i)}\right|$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but even thinking with the conjugate, opening that multiplication gets me the same expression. Not good..

Comment: @IvoTerek \begin{align*} \left|\sum (x_i + y_i)\overline{(x_i + y_i)}\right| &\leq ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + \left|\sum x_i\overline{y_i}\right| + \left|\sum \overline{x_i}y_i\right| \\ &\leq ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2||x||\cdot ||y|| \end{align*} Works for me.

Comment: Oh, that's nice too. I wasn't resisting the impulse of putting $x_i\overline{y_i} + \overline{x_i}y_i = 2\,{\rm Re}(x_i\overline{y_i}) \leq 2|x_iy_i|$ and getting the same thing. Thanks